# Delimited Lookup String in Excel VLookup Formula

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Data
    Table of values

```
                           A                                       B
Life Insurance;Banks;Non-life Insurance;Nonlife Insurance     Manufacturing
Mobile Telecommunications;Fixed Line Telecommunications        Retailing
```

Lookup Values

```
    A                                             Return
Life Insurance                                 Manufacturing
NonLife Insurance                              Manufacturing
Mobile Telecommunications                      Retailing
```

Currently it does

Lookup Values

```
    A                                             Return
Life Insurance                                 Manufacturing
NonLife Insurance                              Retailing
Mobile Telecommunications                      Retailing
```

in the 'return' column I have

=IFERROR(INDEX($F$32:$F$33,MATCH(H31,LEFT($E$32:$E$33,SEARCH(";",$E$32:$E$33,1)-1)),0),IFERROR(INDEX($F$32:$F$33,MATCH(H31,MID($E$32:$E$33, SEARCH(";",$E$32:$E$33) + 1, SEARCH(";",$E$32:$E$33,SEARCH(";",$E$32:$E$33)+1) - SEARCH(";",$E$32:$E$33) - 1)),0),INDEX($F$32:$F$33,MATCH(H31,RIGHT($E$32:$E$33,LEN($E$32:$E$33) - SEARCH(";", $E$32:$E$33, SEARCH(";", $E$32:$E$33) + 1))),0)))

which attempts to look at the left, right and middle options using the ";" as a breakup point and then doing a match and index, it doesn't quite work. Is there a way to  do a vlookup with multiple values in the same column separated by a ';'?

thanks,

Comment: Can you normalize the data first?

Comment: what do you mean by that @Comintern

Comment: Similar but not with the answer you’re looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149619/excel-how-to-vlookup-items-in-a-delimited-list-in-single-cell

Comment: what's the expected result?

Comment: Maybe helpful https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/113287-vlookup-comma-delimited-string

Comment: Normalizing means basically storing the data in a way in which you would not have multiple "data points" in a single field.  If `Life Insurance;Banks;Non-life Insurance;Nonlife Insurance` is a single data point, normalizing it would be splitting it into 3 distinct pieces of data. That may be what you're trying to do, but it does make it a lot easier to evaluate relationships.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("*" & D1 & "*",A:A,0))
```

[image]

---

Also a simple VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP("*" & D1 & "*",A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: @OP: note that `NonLife Insurance` won't match `Non-Life Insurance`. Data needs cleansing first. I also suspect `LifeInsurance` will match `NonLifeInsurance`.

Answer (score 1):

With following data layout

> Column A contains data table
>
> Columns D:E hold values being looked up

You can try below formula (case insensitive) in cell B1

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(";"&$D$1:$D$3&";",";"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")&";",1),$E$1:$E$3)`

Copy down as much as you need.

Note:

I have added `SUBSTITUTE` function to handle extra "-".

You can use `FIND` in place of `SEARCH` to make it case sensitive.